# [solved] Scrambled image using gscam

Tags: ros, gscam, pioneer

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to access canon vc-c50i on a pioneer. The onboard computer has Ubuntu 10.04 and diamondback installed in it. P2OS controls are working fine for the camera. I checked ptz functions.

I tried using gscam to get the video from the camera and see it in image_view.

```
$ roscd gscam/bin
$ export GSCAM_CONFIG="v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw-rgb ! ffmpegcolorspace"

$ rosrun gscam gscam
```

I am getting scrambled image in image view. I am accessing imageview using

```
$ rosrun image_view image_view image:=/gscam/image_raw
```

Cheese is also giving me the same video. Could someone help in this regard?

---

update 1:

I tried with player and I am getting the video stream properly.

---

update 2:

sorted with this environment variable setting. removed the device specification.

```
export GSCAM_CONFIG="v4l2src ! video/x-raw-yuv, width=320, height=240 ! ffmpegcolorspace"
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44149/%5Bsolved%5D-scrambled-image-using-gscam/) by [gauthampdas](https://answers.ros.org/users/3231/gauthampdas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-09-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2012-09-20**:
Instead of changing the title to include "[solved]" we have a mechanism for accepting the solutions to questions where you answer your own question, and then accept the answer. It'd be great if you could do that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From @gauthampdas

sorted with this environment variable setting. removed the device specification.

export GSCAM_CONFIG="v4l2src ! video/x-raw-yuv, width=320, height=240 ! ffmpegcolorspace"

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-10-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0